# Update more records with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following records imported from excel to the database. The record count is 5,00,000.

`EmpId` `Name` `City` `CityId`

`1`     `Ramesh`  `LA`    `?`

`2`     `Kumar`   `NewYork`   `?`

I need to fetch the CityId from other table and insert into this `CityId`

The other table has the alias name for the cities and the cityId

`CityId` `AliasName`

`1`      `LA`

`1`      `LosAngels`

`1`      `Los Angels`

`1`      `LA(USA)`

I would like to call a stored procedure to update all 500000 records, as functions cannot be used for UPDATING record.

**I need CityId field to be updated for each employee from Alias Table**

Comment: Is this an operation you have to perform regularly or just once? If one time only, you don't even need to create a stored procedure, running a script once would be enough.

What kind of database do you use? Sql Server?

Comment: What are your concerns about efficiency? What have you tried and why is it not good enough? To me that looks like a very simple join between two tables. Indexes on the City / AliasName columns would almost certainly help performance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
     update employee
     set cityid = b.cityid
     from employee as a inner join city as b on a.city = b.aliasname
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out.

```
UPDATE UserDetails
SET UserDetails.CityID = City.ID
FROM City
WHERE City.AliasName = UserDetails.City
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to set the `City` as a foreign key rather than adding a redundant data column.

To answer your question, you can achieve this by running the following query.  You can also make this into a stored procedure if it needs to be run occasionally.

```
UPDATE Employees SET CityId = (Select CityId FROM Cities where AliasName = City)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will update the required data:

```
UPDATE Employees SET CityId = ISNULL((Select CityId FROM Cities where AliasName = City),0)
```